# Getting Nonetypes while scraping address on apartments.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making an application that creates a csv of apartments from apartments.com I am using beautiful soup and almost have all necessary information but when I search for address I keep getting Nonetypes
here is an examples

```
<div class="location" title="123 jolly ln, north pole, AK 00001"> 123 jolly ln, north pole, AK 00001 </div>
```

and code I am trying is.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
addr = soup.find("div", class_="location")
print(addr)
```

but I only get None from that

Comment: This code works for me. Maybe the page is loading the data through Ajax and in this case you need to use selenium to grab the data, not just BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should fetch you the address:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<div class="location" title="123 jolly ln, north pole, AK 00001"> 123 jolly ln, north pole, AK 00001 </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
address = soup.find(class_="location").get("title")
print(address)
```

Comment: The way you tried is also a valid approach. All you needed to do is add `.text`. As you are having None that clearly means the portion you are trying to fetch generated dynamically. Try to find out the address in the source code to reassure.